# python saving scripts problems

Tags: python

I am using Windows 7. I installed Python and everything is working fine except the fact that as I am saving python scripts on desktop or anywhere, none of them are opening.

.py files are closing in a blink!

.pyw files are not even responding.

Any help appreciated. I have already uninstalled and reinstalled the software suite but the problem still persists.

[Here are the pictures of the icons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IszH4.png)

Comment: Please clarify "modified the installation"... Sounds like you messed something up and should just reinstall

Comment: python files are text files, they should open with **any** text editor , and .pyw are not important ( they just accelerate the running ) , unless you mean running them ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you run a `.py` file is that a `cmd.exe` window is opened where Python runs your script. But this window will close as soon as your script finishes.

What you can do in this case:

- Add `raw_input()` (python2) or `input()`  to the end of your script to make it pause for input. That wat you can read any output before the window closes.
- Open a `cmd` window and run your scripts from that.

With regard to `.pyw` files, they are themselves responsible for creating a window. So unless those scripts create a GUI you probably won't see anything.